# osx - How to override automatically enabled proxy

Tags: network, macos, proxy

(I am using a 11" MacBook Air, Early 2015, provided by my school)

There is software hard-installed on my computer that automatically enables a proxy (under "System Preferences..." -> "Network" -> "Advanced" -> "Proxies") about every 5 minutes which inadvertently breaks a lot of services like the app store, simply uploading images to imgur, using lightshot at all, a lot of games I play from launching, etc. etc. I am able to use these services for just a few minutes right after I disable the proxy but pretty soon the hard-installed software enables the proxy itself again. I was wondering if there is literally any way around this. Maybe my own program that keeps the proxy disabled, counterproductive to the proxy enabler.

If I am being confusing, let me explain what I go through:

1. I go to do something (play a game, download an app, etc.)
2. It is not working.
3. I click on the apple logo, then choose: "System Preferences..." -> "Network" -> "Advanced" -> "Proxies"
4. I notice "Automatic Proxy Configuration" is enabled, with an address (to a .pac proxy I guess) put in.
5. I simply uncheck "Automatic Proxy Configuration".
6. I click OK, and "Apply".
7. I am able to access the software now. (play a game, or download an app, etc.)
8. Soon, usually just a few minutes, the proxy is magically enabled (checkbox is checked) again.
9. Repeat!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a "legitimate" way around this.  The owner of the machine has installed this, and they desire that it remain turned on.  It would be a poor security measure indeed which could be disabled without the owner's consent in any sort of simple way.

If you have admin access you may be able to determine which process is doing this and terminate it.

I am using a company-supplied MacBook Pro.  If I want to access internal company resources, I have to leave the stuff they've installed in place.  I have admin access, but cannot see some of the software my company has installed.

I believe that you have basically two choices:

- Reinstall El Capitan, overwriting the existing install [this might
  cause problems with access to school resources]
- Install El Capitan on an external drive, then boot from it when you seek 
  to do the things that the proxy is preventing.

Some replacement SSDs come with external cases; you could replace the internal SSD with your own clean El Capitan SSD and then boot from the external one when you need school access.

All of this is probably contrary to some acceptable-use agreement you signed when you accepted the school-supplied machine.  Take care.